# Magento. Issue OAuth oauth_problem=Signature+method+HMAC-SHA1+is+not+supported

Tags: npm, magento

I have issue with Magento. Everything worked well(I don't change anything) but now something going wrong with OAuth part.

I have an error on response statusCode 400 with message **oauth_problem=Signature+method+HMAC-SHA1+is+not+supported**

According to the docs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html#pre-auth-token

> **oauth_signature_method** The name of the signature method used to sign the request. Must be the value **HMAC-SHA1**.

It is strange

**Some info:**
URL -> **http**://54.83.101.160/oauth/token/request

Method -> POST

Headers -> Authorization: *OAuth oauth_consumer_key="1hs2nh9pldf6lwjj837pvh9zjcjgx6f7", oauth_nonce="NFxgRXVTHWb17yQVUyqv5MoNybiY3mX1", oauth_signature="HNko7Bhsxv3IMXRM1qtT1%2Bm4Tyc%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1653582260", oauth_version="1.0"*

I'm using package **oauth-1.0a**(npm)

Code:

```
const OAuth = require('oauth-1.0a');

const OAUTH_METHOD = 'POST';
const OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD = 'HMAC-SHA1';

const OAUTH_REQUEST_HEADERS = (url, consumerKey, consumerSecret) => {
  const oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
      key: consumerKey,
      secret: consumerSecret,
    },
    signature_method: OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD,
    hash_function: sha1HashFunction,
  });
  return oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize({ url, method: OAUTH_METHOD }));
};

const getRequestToken = (host, { consumerKey, consumerSecret }) => {
  const url = `${host}/oauth/token/request`;

  return axios.post(url, {}, {
    headers: OAUTH_REQUEST_HEADERS(url, consumerKey, consumerSecret),
  });
};
```

Help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is going on with Magento documentation. I believe they should update it.
So just change **hmac-sha1** to **hmac-sha256**
https://github.com/request/request/issues/2627

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has been updated and reflects it correctly. It must be "HMAC-SHA256"

Comment: User is sharing a suggestion which can be done in question's comment. As he hasn't enough reputation to do so.